How to inject cron expression value
public class Properties {
   
    @Value("${scheduler.cron:0 0/15 * * * *")
    private String schedulerCron;

    public Properties() {
        //schedulerCron = "0 0/15 * * * *";
    }
    
}

If I do not use @Value and populate the property as I have in constructor, I am able to use it. But I am not able to inject it via @Value. It does not like the expression and gives below error
Encountered invalid @Scheduled method 'scheduler': For input string: "${scheduler.cron:0" '${scheduler.cron:0' in cron expression "${scheduler.cron:0 0/15 * * * *"

My java class where I am using @Scheduled is like below
 @Scheduled(cron = "#{@properties.schedulerCron}")


you are missing a closing bracket, if you add it, it will work: @Value("${scheduler.cron:0 0/15 * * * *}")
